# Are subgroups of order $p^{n-1}$ maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, p-groups, maximal-subgroup

Let $G$ be finite p-group of order $p^n$, I know all maximal subgroups of order $p^{n-1}$
Is it right to say all subgroup of order $p^{n-1}$ are maximal subgroups?
If not, what property $G$ must have to it became true?

Comment: Do you know about Lagrange's theorem...?

Comment: no I don't know it

Comment: As has been suggested, you can use Lagrange's Theorem. Suppose $H$ is a proper subgroup of $G$ having order $p^{n-1}$. Now suppose that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$ (not necessarily proper) that _properly contains_ $H$. The $K$ has order at least ____ , and so by Lagrange's Theorem we must have _____.

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Lagrange's_Theorem_(Group_Theory)

Comment: Lagrange's theorem states that if $H$ is a subgroup of a finite group $G$ then $|H|$ divides $|G|$. You might want to know this before going into the theory of $p$-groups (using this, you can show for instance that every subgroup of a $p$-group is a $p$-group). One interesting thing for $p$-groups which does not hold in general for finite groups is that you have the inverse of Lagrange's theorem : provided that $G$ is a $p$-group, for any $d$ dividing $|G|$ there exists a subgroup of order $d$ in $G$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange's_theorem_%28group_theory%29), for a finite group $G$ the order of a subgroup $H\subset G$ divides the order of $G$. Given that $G$ is a group of order $p^n$ and $H$ is a group of order $p^{n-1}$, if $H$ is not maximal there exists a subgroup $M\subsetneq G$ with $H\subsetneq M$. Then by Lagrange's theorem $|M|$ divides $p^n$ and $p^{n-1}$ divides $|M|$. It follows that $|M|=p^{n-1}$ or $|M|=p^n$, and hence $M=H$ or $M=G$, a contradiction. This shows that $H$ is indeed maximal.